# Java feed cmd arguments from file

Tags: java, linux, windows

I hava java program that depends on argument list to do the work. And now I want to do unit test on windows or linux. So i just wanna feed arguments into program from text file. Without changing anything in program. Is it even possible?

Something like:

```
java MyProgram **-arg "test.txt"**
```

or

```
java MyProgram **< test.txt**
```

or

```
java MyProgram **type text.txt**
```

Everything bolded is ofcourse made up by me and doesn't work, but now I think my point is quite clear.

Comment: How are you testing the program? Why don't you use a proper testing framework like JUnit where you can run `main` manually with whatever arguments you want however many times you want. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Im kinda new to Java. And I want to know if there's language independent thing like that. Just curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

For linux:

```
PROGRAM="java MyProgram "`cat test.txt`
exec $PROGRAM
```

I think, it must be something similar for windows

Answer (score 0):

[`man xargs`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs):

> xargs reads items
>   from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which  can be  protected
>   with  double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines, and executes
>   the command (default is /bin/echo) one or more times with any  initial-
>   arguments  followed  by items read from standard input.

So you can do

```
cat test.txt | xargs java MyProgram
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you pass your file as a parameter and then process it inside your program?
If that is ok with you

you can just run your program as follows

```
java yourclass argfilenamewithpath
```